# AWS regional service availability (Amazon FSx for Lustre)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-regions

I'm trying to follow the [Parallel Cluster tutorial](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/v2/workshops/6735ed89-c2de-4180-904c-40ac9fba7419/en-US/setup/pcluster/pcluster-x86/build) and `pcluster create-cluster` failed. The reason, per `pcluster get-cluster-stack-events`:

> Amazon FSx does not currently support Lustre file system creation in the following Availability Zones: ap-northeast-1c (Service: AmazonFSx; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequest; Request ID: ....; Proxy: null)

I never specified `ap-northeast-1c` — everything in my config refers just to `ap-northeast-1` (i.e. Asia Pacific (Tokyo) region). And checking the [AWS Regional Services List](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/) though, "Amazon FSx for Lustre" is listed as available.

I have no idea why it failed, or how to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: `ap-northeast-1c` is determined by subnet, which the tutorial picks at random. While `ap-northeast-1` *region* does support Lustre file system, not every availability zone does; using the subnet that corresponds to `ap-northeast-1a` solved the problem.